# Hibernate ID column always last in generated SQL

Tags: hibernate

I have a model that looks like this:

```
@MappedSuperclass
@AccessType("field")
public abstract class BaseEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "generator")
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "MODEL")
@AccessType("field")
public class Model extends BaseEntity {
    @Column(name="ABC")
    private String abc;
}
```

No matter what I try I cannot seem to be able to move the location of the ID column in the generated INSERT or UPDATE sql queries. ID always ends up as the last column:

```
insert into MODEL (ABC, ID) values (?, ?)
```

Is there any way to force it otherwise?

Comment: Why do you care? The order doesn't matter.

Comment: It does in Oracle if the column ABC is a CLOB then it MUST be last.

Comment: Do you have some reference to back up this claim? Hibernate seems to work fine with clobs and oracle. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644559/hibernate-on-oracle-mapping-string-property-to-clob-column for example. Isn't it in the table (and not in the insert statement) that the CLOB must be at last position?

Comment: This describes my exact same issue: http://www.odi.ch/weblog/posting.php?posting=496

Comment: Have you tried using an AttributeOverride, either on the Model class, or on an overridden getter for the ID field?

Comment: I had tried the former (changed column name to IDXX but not the position), the latter I just tried but doesn't seem to work at all (maybe because the base class is using `@AccessType("field")`?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known Hibernate limitation; see [this thread](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2396711) for details.

Since Hibernate will order generated SQL fields alphabetically, why not change the name of the CLOB field to ensure is comes last, such as by pre-pending it with "zzz" so that it becomes `zzzAbc`?

Comment: The order in the `create table` is not the problem, the ID is located first there as you mentioned. However, Hibernate still builds the query such that ID comes last :( in the `insert`.